# how handle a path ($1)

Tags: bash, parameter

I've:

```
/home/wms/mp3/
```

and

```
/home/wms/tmp/
```

Inside ~/tmp my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
br=64
for a in "$1"*.mp3 ;
do ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab $br "$br""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$br"].mp3" ; done
```

I do:

```
/home/wms/tmp/./script.sh /home/wms/mp3/
```

How I handle $1?

because "@1" concides with /home/wms/mp3/first1

${a%.*} cuts extension file

but the path is not correct: this script runs only if I runs it inside ~/mp3

Answer (score 2):

I use basename $a to extract the name of file, and then build the path with the temporal directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
br=64
mkdir -p _tmp
for a in "$1"*.mp3 ; do
aux=$(basename ${a})
ffmpeg -i "$a" -ar 44100 -ab $br "$br""_tmp/${aux%.*}_["$br"].mp3" 
done
```

Comment: Exactly is: aux=$(basename "$a") this keep spaces inside filename